Unicode-math Problem Finding Local Font Files
I am trying to specify some local font files via the fontspec package for my non-math fonts and then unicode-math package for my math fonts. I need to be able to specify the fonts from local files in the directory. I don't want to have to rely on system fonts or fonts installed in texmf.
Here is an abbreviated file structure of my project.
fonts/
    serif/ 
        LibertinusSerif-Bold.otf
        LibertinusSerif-BoldItalic.otf
        LibertinusSerif-Italic.otf
        LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf
        LibertinusSerif-Semibold.otf
        LibertinusSerif-SemiBoldItalic.otf
    sans_serif/
        LibertinusSans-Bold.otf
        LibertinusSans-Italic.otf
        LibertinusSans-Regular.otf
    mono/
        JuliaMono-Regular.ttf
        JuliaMono-Bold.ttf
    math/
        LibertinusMath-Regular.otf
        STIX2Math.otf
preamble.tex
main.tex

in preamble.tex I have the following. I want to use LibertinusMath as my math font, except for the calligraphic alphabet which I want to use from STIX2Math.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[Path=fonts/serif/]{LibertinusSerif}[
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic
]
\setsansfont[Path=fonts/sans_serif/]{LibertinusSans}[
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic
]
\setmonofont[Path=fonts/mono/]{JuliaMono}[
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
]
\setmathfont[
    Path={./fonts/math/},
    Extension = {.otf}
]{LibertinusMath-Regular}
\setmathfont[
    Path = {./fonts/math/},
    Extension = {.otf},
    range={cal,bfcal},
    Scale={MatchUppercase}
]{STIX2Math}

And then in my main document I have something like this in my preamble.
\input{premable.tex]

When I try to compile this I get the following error. No PDF is created. I'm guessing because it can't find the local font? Or doesn't look in the right place? It also doesn't matter if I try Path=./fonts/math/ or Path=fonts/math. Both fail with the same error.
</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus-fonts/LibertinusMath-Regular.otf>
! error:  (file ) (type 0): cannot find file ''
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

However, if I comment out the second setmathfont (the one for STIX2Math) it compiles fine. Alternatively, if I move STIX2Math.otf so that Path does not have to be specified it also seems to compile (i.e., if I move STIX2Math.otf to the same level as main.tex and remove the Path key from the setmathfont).
Does anyone know what the issue might be here?
For reference, I am using TexLive 2023 and compiling with LuaLatex. I am also using the memoir package if it matters.

apart from the error on stix2, libertinus came from the standard texlive place not your copy, /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus-fonts/LibertinusMath-Regular.otf

I wouldn't have thought it mattered but you could remove the extra {} used in the math examples. They certain;y are not needed in Path and Extension keys

@DavidCarlisle Thanks. I removed the parentheses in both setmathfont and now it compiles no error. Does that make any sense to you? Should I consider it fixed or is it just using the system installed fonts somewhere else on my computer?

you can tell if it is using the system fonts the same way I could tell on the fragment of log you posted, the full path to the ttf file is printed in the log at the end

You should remove the spurious {} in the key values here
\setmathfont[
    Path={./fonts/math/},
    Extension = {.otf}
]{LibertinusMath-Regular}
\setmathfont[
    Path = {./fonts/math/},
    Extension = {.otf},
    range={cal,bfcal},
    Scale={MatchUppercase}
]{STIX2Math}

